# How can I map the tabe in vim in putty terminal

Tags: windows-7, vim, putty

I am new new to vim and I have learned `tabe n` and `tabe p`
I don't know anything about mapping.

Is there any way that in putty in vim if I press `f5 --> tabe n`   And `f6 ---> tabe p`

Also where to write those map commands .

I looked on Internet and find some commands but was not able to figure out where to write those commands.

Also is there any ready to use script or configuration file where some has already mapped those keys so that I can see what other people are doing on daily basis so that I don't need to spent time on those

Comment: @Saathya , maddham maddham teri gili hassi  . . . . . .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you understand the Vim modes, writing a mapping is very straightforward.

1. Choose the mode (cp. `:help map-modes`), e.g. normal mode = `:nnoremap`. Using the `*noremap` is preferred, because it avoids complications from other mappings applying.
2. Select an unused key. It needs to be written in Vim's notation, e.g. `<F5>`
3. The general syntax is `:map {lhs} {rhs}`, where `{rhs}` is what you have usually typed manually. `:help map.txt` has all the details. To make them permanent, place them into your `~/.vimrc` file (create it if necessary), which contains your user options and customizations.

For example:

```
:nnoremap <F5> :tabe n<CR>
:nnoremap <F6> :tabe p<CR>
```

Comment: wow that worked, thanks buddy that was my first mapping.